# How to clear/delete a cache variable

Tags: cmake

Trying to get `find_path` to do what I want.

```
find_path(temmp include/help.h)
message("temmp= ${temmp}")
```

help.h is found.  The output is  `temmp= /usr/local/toolA`

```
find_path(temmp include/foo.shoe)
message("temmp= ${temmp}")
```

foo.shoe does not exist (not found).  The output is `temmp= /usr/local/toolA`
The cache variable exists, so the variable (temmp) is untouched.

I try and clear the cache var with this:

```
set (temmp "" CACHE INTERNAL "")
find_path(temmp include/help.h)
message("temmp= ${temmp}")
```

No change.  The variable is cleared, but still exists.  The output is `temmp=`
(`find_path` does not run.)

How can I delete the `temmp` variable from the cache?  (I want to force the `find_path` to run again.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [`unset`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/unset.html):

```
unset(temmp CACHE)
```

As an aside, the [`find_path`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_path.html) calls should be more like:

```
find_path(temmp help.h include)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this **does NOT work if you have both a *normal-variable* and a *cached-variable* using the same name** (you would be forced to call `unset` yet another time, but without `CACHE` parameter).