# 'find_library' returns the same value in the loop in CMake

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to loop over a list with library names in CMake. In each iteration I search the library with `find_library`:

```
set(LIB_NAMES "TKBO;TKBRep;")
set(LIBS_DIR /usr/local/OCCT/7.2.0/libd)


FOREACH(LIB_NAME ${LIB_NAMES})
  FIND_LIBRARY(LIB ${LIB_NAME} PATHS ${LIBS_DIR})
  MESSAGE("<<${LIB_NAME}>>")
  MESSAGE("<<${LIB}>>")
  target_link_libraries(mySharedLib ${LIB})
ENDFOREACH()
```

For the above, I get the output:

```
<<TKBO>>
<</usr/local/OCCT/7.2.0/libd/libTKBO.dylib>>
<<TKBRep>>
<</usr/local/OCCT/7.2.0/libd/libTKBO.dylib>>
```

While LIB_NAME updates, `FIND_LIBRARY` seems to be using an outdated value. I also tried to explicitly `UNSET(LIB_NAME)` at the end of the loop but that didn't help either.

What could I be overlooking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of `find_library` is a *CACHED* variable, and once the library is found, the variable is not updated.

When search different libraries, it is better to use different result variables:

```
FOREACH(LIB_NAME ${LIB_NAMES})
  set(LIB_VAR "LIB_${LIB_NAME}") # Name of the variable which stores result of the search
  FIND_LIBRARY(${LIB_VAR} ${LIB_NAME} PATHS ${LIBS_DIR})
  target_link_libraries(mySharedLib ${${LIB_VAR}})
ENDFOREACH()
```

Here `LIB_TKBO` variable is used for `TKBO` library, and `LIB_TKBRep` variable - for `TKBRep` library.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by:

```
UNSET(LIB_NAME CACHE)
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308847/how-to-clear-delete-a-cache-variable) for a similar problem.